# PL/SQL script sub query in variable array

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

hey guys what im trying to do is pull a list of account ids that are related to a primary account id without joining the table as its gigantic then use that list to pull out the relevant information from the data table i get an error saying it expecting something other then = on line 3

the data table does not contain the primary account id 
the account_lookup table has account _id and primary account id in the same row IE

```
row ID | primary_account_id | account_id
 1     |          1         |     1
 2     |          1         |     2


declare
   acc_id number(10,0) := 5500704;
   p_acc_id number(10,0) := (select Primary_account_id from lookup_tbl where account_id = acc_id); 
   type array_t is table of number(10,0);
   array array_t := (select account_id from lookup_tbl where primary_account_id = p_acc_id);  

end;

select account_id, profit
from data_tbl where account_id in array_t
```

Comment: don't know if it will solve your overall issue but putting a space between the acc_id and the := should solve the error you are getting at the moment (you will also need to do the same for pa_acc_id)

Comment: tried that it did not resolve the error "ERROR: ORA-06550: line 3, column 11:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expectingone of thfollowing:  constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national character
   nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue.

Comment: Sorry didn't read your code correctly you need to merge the two lines into one.  Or move the second part out of the declaration section.  So your first line would become acc_id number(10,0) := 5500704;

Comment: ERROR: ORA-06550: line 3, column 30:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of 
the following:

Comment: I doubt you can use `select` result and assign it to a variable in the declaration section. We usually use cursors here. However, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. By `pull` you mean you want to display this data on the screen (i.e., query data only)? If so, then pl/sql is not the way to go, pl/sql can write what you want into tables and then you can query them using pure sql. If no, then please clarify where are you writing the result of your query

Comment: thanks hank cursors might be the way to go then ive tried researching them but i am struggling to find a way to make them work in this case all that is required is to display them.

Comment: clarification to the above comment, thanks hank cursors might be the way to go then ive tried researching them but i am struggling to find a way to make them work in this case all that is required is to be able to display the information from the data table then i can export the results to a csv its not required to write them to anywhere. based on your answer i may have the wrong understanding of what PL/SQL is i thought it was simply oracles flavor of native SQL ill do some further research there could you help with the cursors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hey i have modified the code snippet to elimintae the error you are facing. Please try and let me know for any issues.

DROP TYPE p_acc_tab;


-- Creating permament SQL object to eliminate the error occured
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE 
p_acc_tab 
IS TABLE OF NUMBER; 


DECLARE          
acc_id NUMBER := 5500704;          
p_acc_id p_acc_tab;        
type array_tab        
IS          
TABLE OF NUMBER;          
array_t array_tab;        
BEGIN          
-- First bulk collect as you don want to use join as gigantic data present          
SELECT Primary_account_id           
BULK COLLECT          
INTO p_acc_id          
FROM lookup_tbl          
WHERE account_id = acc_id;                    

--Second bulk collect with EXISTS condition to check for the account_id for respective primary account_id          
SELECT account_id           
BULK COLLECT          
INTO array_t          
FROM lookup_tbl t_tab          
WHERE EXISTS            
(SELECT 1            
FROM TABLE(p_acc_id) tab            
WHERE tab.column_value = t_tab.Primary_account_id            
);        
END;
```

Comment: hey mate this looks like its exactly what i am after however i get three errors

Comment: ORA-06550: line 26, column 20:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
ORA-06550: line 26, column 14:
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
ORA-06550: line 20, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: ORA-06550: line 25, column 26:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "L_TAB"."PRIMARY_ACCOUNT_ID": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 18, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

Untested but try something like the below.

```
declare
   acc_id number(10,0) := 5500704;
   p_acc_id number(10,0); 

   type array_t is  table of number(10,0);
   my_array array_t;  

   cursor c_blah is
   select account_id, profit
    from data_tbl where account_id in array_t;

begin

  select primary_account_id 
  into p_acc_id
  from lookup_tbl 
  where account_id = acc_id;  

  select account_id 
  bulk collect into my_array
  from lookup_tbl 
  where primary_account_id = p_acc_id;

  for v_row in c_blah loop

     dbms_output.put_line(' account_id = ' || v_row.account_id || ' : ' || v_row.profit);      

  end loop;


end;
```

Comment: got this error ERROR: ORA-06550: line 20, column 27:
PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
ORA-06550: line 19, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: also is it possible to do this without the loop IE select account_id, profit
from data_tbl where account_id in array_t

Comment: There was a typo in the second select I have fixed this now.  Whether the loop is required depends on how you want to use the data. But to output the data or process it further you probably need some kind of a loop

Comment: I am just going to paste the query into tableau

Comment: Just got to a computer to test and made a couple of minor tweaks just for accuracy.

Comment: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated